# How are Pokemon games ordered in terms of plot/lore?

Tags: pokemon-series

What is the chronological/timeline order of Pokemon games? For example, here are the games I will get/have:

- Pokemon Lets Go
- Pokemon Leaf Green
- Pokemon Black (and its sequel)
- Pokemon OmegaRuby
- Pokemon Soul Silver
- Pokemon Y
- Pokemon Ultra Sun
- Pokemon Platinum
- Pokemon Sword and Shield

In which order should I play them to progress through the story in chronological order?

Comment: Are you asking about what order in lore or time-line the Pokemon games go in?

Comment: Play them in order. There isn't a best way.

Comment: I'm fairly sure he's referring to the order based on the game's story, as opposed to the release date of the games themselves or say gen 1 -> gen 2 -> gen 3 -> etc

Answer (score 1):

The Pokemon games in order of plot [based on Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/History_of_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world):

1. Red, Blue, Yellow, Ruby, Sapphire and Emerald. All their remakes occur at the same time. Let's Go Pikachu/Eevee is thought to occur at the same time in an alternate universe, since it features the same story as Yellow in beating Team Rocket but has changes to Red, Blue, and Mina that aren't consistent with the main story (source [1](https://www.gamesradar.com/au/pokemon-timeline/) and [2](https://www.twingalaxies.com/feed_details.php/2603/theory-we-know-the-timeline-placement-of-pokemon-lets-go-pikachu-eevee/1)).
2. Gold, Silver, Crystal, Heart Gold, Soul Silver, Diamond, Pearl and Platinum
3. Pokemon Black and White
4. Pokemon Black 2, White 2, X, and Y
5. Pokemon Sun and Moon. Pokemon Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon occur at the same time but in an alternate universe.

It is not yet clear where Pokemon Sword and Shield place in the timeline.

The order of the plot means little for the actual stories for each game though. Hence I would not recommend playing them in order of the plot, but rather play them in the chronological order of game release e.g. Red & Blue to Sword & Shield, starting with Fire Red in your case. Or alternatively start with Sword & Shield, as it's the most recently released game and hence more people are likely to be playing that currently than the other games - that helps for finding people for trades, raids etc.

Answer (score -1):

Pokemon games are separated by generations, you could also easily just start chronologically and be fine as well but with your current list of games you should play:

Either Pokemon Leaf Green or Let's go which are both just remakes of the Gen 1 games of Red and Blue. If you prefer the 2d games which are more classic go withe Leaf Green but if you want a more streamlined and modern experience go with Let's go. The rest is really up to you from there.